# Image load fails - Jquery capture event & try again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

I'm looking to do the following steps to try to load an image and if it fails (because the image doesn't exist) create the image and then load it. My concern is on the second load the image would be cached as failed image/url and therefore wouldn't load the second time.

Steps:
- try to load image.
- if this fails - jQuery captures event - ajax to php, create image, move into place.
- Then load image. (and all future users can use the saved image that was moved into place).

The reason I'm trying this method is of 200,000 users only accounts that are viewed will need the image (maybe 10%) - thus less data.

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Jquery to check if the image failed:

```
$("img").on("error", function(){...});
```

thanks

Comment: better do this in server by php, when make html output, first try to load the image, and if not put default, is an idea

Comment: You mean using Curl to check for the image? I thought about this but it rather not need an ongoing Curl call for each of these page loads.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón is right, do the job on server side, by checking if image exists and if not create image, serve it!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure my answer is correct, so feel free anybody to let me know if I am wrong. I think you can modify your image URL to have a version ending, like `'...?v=4'` and if the image failed to load, just increase the version for that user to `'...?v=5'`. You can use `sessionStorage` for that purpose, with a unique key identifying the image itself and the value to be a counter which will show how many times did the image fail to load. Each time a fail occurs increment the counter or add the image to `sessionStorage` with a counter of 2 in the case when the error occurs for the first time in the session. In order for this to work you might need to synchronize the version with a server-side version for the user. By the way, you can work this out on server-side as well and then you will not need the versioning.

Comment: I like your idea. I believe it will work - will test it out - thankyou for taking the time :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create ajax call to get an image URL.

In you PHP script check if image url gives you `200` or `404` status. You can use `file_get_contents();`

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/display-image-from-url/6334

On `200` case, display image, image from file_get_contents().

On `404` return display fallback image.